# unitary matrix that never converts unit vector into a vector with zero entry previously 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is a unitary matrix. Let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ be $n$-dimensional vectors. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be $[0,0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0]^T$ - where every entry except one is zero and that single element at entry $i$ is $1$. (unit vector)

Is there a known class of unitary matrices $U$ that $U\mathbf{x}$ does not result in entry $i$ being zero?

What happens if $n$ is infinite dimension?

Comment: the class of unitary matrices for which $e_i^T U e_i \ne 0$

Answer (score 1):

The $i$-th unit vector is $e_i$. 
The $i$-th component of a vector $x$ is $x \cdot e_i$, where $\cdot$ is the scalar product.

So you ask for $(U e_i) \cdot e_i \ne 0$. This means
$$
0 \ne (Ue_i) \cdot e_i = u_i \cdot e_i = (u_i)_i
$$
where $u_i$ is the $i$-th column vector of $U$.

So you want those unitary matrices, with all diagonal elements non-zero.